# Fiware Orion ContexBroker connection with Freeboard.io

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, freeboard

I was trying to connect fiware contexBroker to freeboard.io but ı dont know how to fill the neccessary information.

I can't learn what is my FIWARE-SERVICEPATH, TYPE, ID.How can I find these informations and fill.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzQZB.png)

The contextBroker query that I have used is below :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEMqw.png)

Comment: It seems that the question lack imporant information... I understand that the "enter image description here" should show something more meaningful.

Comment: Thank you for your command. I can't learn what is my FIWARE-SERVICEPATH, TYPE, ID.How can I find these informations and fill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following values for that fields:

- Fiware-Service : `/`
- Fiware-ServicePath :  (a blank space)
- X-AUTH-TOKEN:  (a blank space)
- TYPE: your entity type
- ID: your entity id